# Projective dimension of locally free sheaf on a Cartier divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $\mathbb{C}$, let $D\hookrightarrow X$ be an effective Cartier divisor. Is it true for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ which is locally free on $D$ (i.e. a pushforward of a locally free sheaf on $D$), that there exists a locally free resolutions of lenght one of $\mathcal{F}$?

I understand this is true for $X$ smooth, but I am not sure how well this generalizes to a non-smooth case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.

Fix an ample bundle $L$ on $X$. Then, $\mathcal{F}\otimes L^n$ is globally generated for large $n$ and thus we have a surjection $H^0(\mathcal{F}\otimes L^n)\otimes L^{-n}\to\mathcal{F}$. Let $E$ be the kernel. It suffices to show that $E$ is locally free. But locally, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_D^r$. Rest follows from the fact that the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_D$ is just $\mathcal{O}_X(-D)$, which is a line bundle, by your assumption on $D$ being a Cartier divisor.

Comment: I am not sure about the last step. I understand that locally you have $\mathcal{O}_X^N\to \mathcal{O}_D^k$ for some fixed $N$ and $k$, but how can you express it using the restriction map $\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_D$?

Comment: @ArkadijBojko  Locally, near any point, lift a basis of $\mathcal{O}_D$ to $\mathcal{O}_X^N$ and show that these lifts form part of a basis for $\mathcal{O}_X^N$ and the rest should be clear.